# Conditional probability of p(C|A or B)

Tags: probability, self-study, bayesian, conditional-probability

I'm trying to express conditional probability of $p(C|A \cup B)$ (probability of $C$, given $A$ or $B$) using $p(C|A)$, $p(C|B)$, and $p(C|A \cap B)$.

Using Venn's diagram I came up with:
$$p(C|A \cup B) = p(C|A) + p(C|B) - p(C|A \cap B).$$

Is this correct? How can I prove this more formally?

Comment: I suspect you want to replace the plus sign with a union $\cup$ symbol. Thr former is an arithmetic operator. The latter is a set operator.

Comment: @Taylor The textbook I was using (Jaynes, Probability Theory) was using +, but I can go with $\vee$ if that is more common.

Comment: 1. Hint: define $A$ and $B$ as independent coin flips and let $C=AB$. What happens?   2. Can you also show your work with Venn diagrams?

Comment: Another textbook using  $\plus$ for union (of events) and concatenation for intersection of events is  A. Papoulis (1984) Probability, Random Variables and Stochastic Processes. But using the more common/modern(?) notation $A\cup B,~A\cap B$ is more likely to be understood.  (@user135519 please 9 note also the difference between $\vee$ and $\cup$)

Comment: @JuhoKokkala Thanks for heads up about unions. Spending some more time with this formula I realised that it is definitely wrong, but I am not sure how to proof that $p(C|A\cup B)$ cannot be expressed using only  $p(C|A)$, $p(C|B)$, and $p(C|A \cap B)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but your formula is wrong. Simplest similar formula is below:

$$p(C|A \cup B) =\frac{p(C(A \cup B))}{p(A \cup B)}=\frac{p(CA) + p(CB) - p(CAB)}{p(A) + p(B) - p(AB)}=$$

$$=\frac{p(C|A)p(A) + p(C|B)p(B) - p(C|AB)p(AB)}{p(A) + p(B) - p(AB)}$$